# Qt Android Fullscreen bottom gap

Tags: android, qt, fullscreen

I am having an issue when I deploy a Qt application on Android. Basically, my application contains two QML items, grouped into a stacked widget. It is a very simple code, but I can't remove the bottom grey bar as shown here:
[Fullscreen failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QddIS.png)

And my main code is:

```
QtWebView::initialize();
QApplication a(argc, argv);

MainWindow w;
w.setWindowTitle("Speakers Discovery");
w.showFullScreen();

return a.exec();
```

With the instantiation of the widget inside the MainWindow constructor:

```
m_page = new QQuickWidget(this);
m_page->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/loading_page.qml"));
```

With the .QML of the object displayed:

```
Item {
width: Screen.width
height: Screen.height
visible: true

    Rectangle
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"
        Image { source: "qrc:/bg.jpg"; fillMode: Image.Stretch; anchors.fill: parent;  opacity: 0.4 }
    }
}
```

I had the same issue on windows, but changing showFullScreen to showMaximized made the trick. Do you have any clues for Android ?

Regards,

Julien.

Comment: From what I know, the width and the height will be overwritten at runtime by the os itself. You can try to set a very small width/height like 100x100 to check, it should remain the same size. I assume that the gap at the bottom is where you should have the 3 android buttons (Home, return, tasks).